# Interface does not contain a definition for property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Firstly, I am not a very experienced .net developer, so please forgive me if this question is insane.

I have created a bunch of models which implement my interface IEntity.  All I want the interface to do (for now) is to ensure those models contain a Created property to store the date.

I would like to neglect adding a Created value to each instance, and let some common code handle that, which is where I'm encountering the problem.

The following code produces a build error:

```
public class Service<IEntity>
{
    // other code omitted 
    public virtual void Insert(IEntity entity)
    {
        entity.Created = DateTime.Now;

        // other code omitted
    }
}
```

> Error 15  'IEntity' does not contain a definition for 'Created' and no
>   extension method 'Created' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

But here is my definition of IEntity, and of course implementations of IEntity will always have a Created property.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

So is there a way to do what I want to do, or should I just forget about trying to handle Created in this way?

Comment: Please check your reference of IEntity, I think these thing should build successfully

Comment: Well it went to the <IEntity> bit at the top of the class, because it is a generic.    I've edited my question to show this as it seems it might be relevant.

Comment: That should work fine. If there is a problem it is outside of this code.

Comment: What you are doing is Generic type in service class, so IEntity is generic type not your interface, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx . You can achieve it by remove <IEntity> in Service class

Comment: I actually found this to be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx     That's what I want, a generic but with a constraint that only implementations of IEntity use this - then the build error goes away.

Comment: It even says this:  "Why Use Constraints?  If you want to examine an item in a generic list to determine whether it is valid or to compare it to some other item, the compiler must have some guarantee that the operator or method it has to call will be supported by any type argument that might be specified by client code."   -- PERFECT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found to be suitable was to use Constraints.  So the code became this:

```
public class Service<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    // other code omitted 
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        entity.Created = DateTime.Now;

        // other code omitted
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

This allows me to use this class with any of the "bunch of models which implement my interface IEntity" I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the cursor within the `IEntity` parameter type of the `Insert` method and press <kbd>F12</kbd>, it'll go to the definition of `IEntity`.

Make sure it's the one you pasted, and you don't have a different `IEntity` in a different namespace somewhere which has caused the confusion.

I've mocked up your example and it works fine for me.

The below compiles and the test passes.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace Tests
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
        DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass : IEntity
    {
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private readonly DateTime _exampleDate;

        public UnitTest1()
        {
            _exampleDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public virtual void Insert(IEntity entity)
        {
            entity.Created = _exampleDate;
            // other code ommitted
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            MyClass myTest = new MyClass();
            Insert(myTest);

            Assert.AreEqual(_exampleDate, myTest.Created);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you've at least confirmed that part.    It seems my problem is trying to create a service that will handle multiple entities/models and that has led to design flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are not using another IEntity in the Method then yours? Check your using statements. 
There also seems to be a naming conflict with "Created" as it is colored strangely.

Comment: The colours in the question don't appear the same as in Visual Studio.